# How to use MT (or similar) RNG algorithm in CPP implementation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, mersenne-twister

I want to implement MT alg in CPP (I just can't use C++11 sadly)
I've found a lot of algorithms like SFMT, dSFMT, some versions of Tiny MT etc; but as I saw the documentation of those algs, I think they works for range like <0,2) (from doxygen documentation)

Need any ideas how to replace basic RNG algorithm

```
SRAND(TIME(NULL))
```

With something better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) provides quite a few thread-safe random generators, and they work with C++98.

Comment: Is "thread-safe" == no global state, or are there any parallel rng i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want Boost dependency there are multiple standalone MT implementations

[Mersenne Twister 1](http://www.bedaux.net/mtrand/)

[Mersenne Twister 2](http://fmg-www.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/mtwist.html)

[Mersenne Twister 3..n](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html)